# how to delete a record by using a class method?

Tags: python, django, django-models

please tell me how can I delete an entry in the table using the method of the model.

Now I delete an entry from the view with the following code:

view.py:

```
def admin_sends(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post = request.POST
        Sends.objects.filter(id=post['delete']).delete()

    all_entries = Sends.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('admin_sends.html', {
        'all_entries': all_entries
    })
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models


class Sends(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField()
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    message = models.TextField(max_length=500)
```

but is wise to keep the function of removing the entries in the model class:
models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Sends(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField()
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    message = models.TextField(max_length=500)


    def delete_entrie(self, del_id):
        ?????????????????????????
```

views.py:

```
def admin_sends(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post = request.POST
        ??????????????????????????

    all_entries = Sends.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('admin_sends.html', {
        'all_entries': all_entries
    })
```

Comment: The delete method should be a part of the ORM you are using. I haven't used Django but SQLAlchemy provides a `delete()` method via the `session`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add class method this way, decorate method with [classmethod](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#classmethod):

```
class Sends(models.Model):
    ...

    @classmethod
    def delete_entrie(cls, del_id):
        cls.objects.filter(id=del_id).delete()
```

Call it:

```
Sends.delete_entire(id_)
```

Answer (score 0):

There already is a method, `delete`, on models in Django.

So your view could look like::

```
def admin_sends(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post = request.POST
        Sends.objects.get(id=post['delete']).delete()

    ...
```

Meaning "get the object with the matching ID and call the delete method on it."